# Smarty vs Twig differences

Tags: symfony, smarty, twig

My team is starting to develop some new middle-size website with CMS, we have our custom developed CMS but we are forced to use Symfony2 in this particular project, and because we have a lot of different code that we could reuse in a new project.

So I would like to ask: What is the difference between `Smarty`  (we are using it in our CMS) and `Twig` (used in Symfony2)?  Would you suggest to rewrite functionality from `Smarty` into `Twig`, or just add some `Smarty` libraries (bundles) into Symfony (if there are any of them available)?

Is there big difference between them? After quick read of `Twig` documentation it seems that there is no really big difference in syntax between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how much Smarty files you have, but if you have some files I recommend to rewrite them to Twig, as that is the default template engine which is optimalised in Symfony2.
If you have a lot of files, I recommend to add Smarty as a template engine in Symfony2 (with [the Noiselabs/SmartyBundle](http://knpbundles.com/noiselabs/SmartyBundle)) and use Smarty for your templates.